# NotAllowedError on front main page '/'

Tags: function, google-app-engine, exception

I tried to set the Main Page `'/'` for users to **login or not login**, but I get a `NotAllowedError`. This works in the local server. However, it does not seem to work in the real public server.

Does `NotAllowedError` mean complying to Google App Engine standards of not putting a login on the front page or maybe its something else?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~map-jobs/2.371277816538602179/main.py", line 294, in get
    user_url = users.create_login_url() # raise NotAllowedError
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 256, in create_login_url
    raise NotAllowedError
NotAllowedError
```

Here is my `MainHandler`:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    profile=''
    if user:
      profile = Profile.query(Profile.user_id==user.user_id())
      if profile.count() <= 0:
        profile = Profile()
        profile.user_id = user.user_id()
        profile.email = user.email()
        profile.firstname = user.nickname()
        profile_key = profile.put()
      else:
        profile_key = Profile.query(Profile.user_id==user.user_id())
      profile = profile_key.get()
      current_user = 'Hello, '+ user.nickname()
      user_url = logout_url
      title = "Click to logout from Google."
    else:
      current_user = 'Google Sign in'
      user_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri) # raise NotAllowedError
      title = "Click to sign in with your Google Account."
    values = {
      'current_user' : current_user,
      'user_url' : user_url,
      'profile' : profile,
    }
    self.render_html('index.html',values)
```

Here is part of my `webapp2.WSGIApplication`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: map-jobs
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|woff|ttf|svg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|woff|ttf|svg))

- url: /templates/.*
  script: templates.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Comment: You haven't shown your app.yaml and what sort of auth (for instance google apps, openid etc) that you have enabled. My guess on the limited info, something like the following is happening, you have auth for an app domain login, but the user is already logged into google, but not the google app domain, so can't create the login url. You should elaborate on your setup.

Comment: I have added my app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just made a mistake. I should use **Google Accounts API** instead of **Google Apps Domain** in my Application settings.

Comment: yep thought it would be something like that.

Comment: The setting in this conversation is regarding the application login (GAE Login) and OAuth Login which could be found inside Google API Console using an API key. It's hard to replicate and explain, but this involves using two authentications. Only one login should be used. As soon as you figure out which one to use, the user can use the information coming from the API.