# NotAllowedError using users.create_login_url in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I am having trouble with a very basic example using `users.create_login_url` in Google App Engine, based on the example code in the [How-to guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/). The example works fine in the local development server but not when deployed to appspot.com.

```
import webapp2
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import users

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
        self.response.write(login_url)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', 'Main'),
], debug=True)
```

Previous questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676367/notallowederror-on-front-main-page) suggest the problem is using Google Apps domain instead of Google Accounts API, which I think refers to the setting pictured below. Altering these settings has not fixed the problem.

What is likely to be causing this?

[image]

Comment: what is happening actually? how does this generated url look like?

Comment: It should generate a url like /ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://my-app.appspot.com&ltmpl=gm&shdf=... which sends the user to a log in page and then back to the original page.  Instead it throw NotAllowedError from the line login_url = users.create_login_url('/')

Comment: Might work correctly in incognito mode (could be wrong user logged into to Google account)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced it on my end and I noticed there is an issue with your code (a syntax error).
On the following line remove the prime on ‘Main’ and try again:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/', Main), ], debug=True)
```

If you run the code again, you ‘ll be able to get a the result displayed. 
Also make sure the handlers are correct on the app.yaml file.
Your App Engine setting seems to be fine and nothing should be changed on that page unless you want to use a different option for Authentication. By default your app will use Google Accounts for authentication.

You can use the following code to run a simple Login Page:

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    # [START user_details]
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            nickname = user.nickname()
            logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
            greeting = 'Welcome, {}! (<a href="{}">sign out</a>)'.format(
                nickname, logout_url)
        else:
            login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
            greeting = '<a href="{}">Sign in</a>'.format(login_url)
        # [END user_details]
        self.response.write(
            '<html><body>{}</body></html>'.format(greeting))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Main),
], debug=True)
```

And for app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```